# UPDATE TABLE без транзакции

Tags: mysql, mysqli, innodb

Имеется таблица innoDB с 200 млн записей. При обновлении больших объемов данных в этой таблице, например по вторичному ключу k:

```
UPDATE TABLE t1 SET field1=1 WHERE k=1
```

как я понимаю, мой UPDATE запускает транзакцию. Все остальные запросы UPDATE и INSERT к таблице выстраиваются в очередь и ждут завершения транзакции.

Задача выполнять UPDATE без транзакции таком образом, что

- как только находится запись удовлетворяющая условию WHERE - она
  обновляется;
- mySQL пропускает другие запросы на изменение таблицы;
- мой UPDATE в это время продолжает искать и изменять остальные
  записи таблицы.

Возможно ли это реализовать?

Делать UPDATE "маленькими порциями", например через LIMIT или WHERE id>start AND id<=end не предлагать)

Comment: *Задача выполнять UPDATE без транзакции* Любой запрос - это транзакция. Высказанное желание в принципе невозможно реализовать.

Comment: т.е. в любом случае другие запросы insert/update должны ожидать завершения моего запроса?  и никак иначе?

Comment: В случае MySQL, InnoDB и наличия индекса по полю `k` предварительный `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` позволит работать тем запросам, которые не затрагивают записи, подпадающие под критерий.